# CSS/HTML Cant use margin on text inside header and its going outside it

Tags: css

```css
html {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #32CD32;
}

#background {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #e800e8, #a800a8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #880088;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}

#title {
  margin-right: 3vw;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

#header-img {
  margin-right: 53vw;
  transform: scale(2.3);
  margin-bottom: 0.8vh;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-link {
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header id="header">
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <h1 id="title">Nebula Coin</h1>
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/202463/isolated/lists/1b4829ac9ea7a1093b4abb1fb0b2f4cf-american-dollar-bill-flat-icon.png" alt="" id="header-img" />
    <button class="nav-link">1</button>
    <button class="nav-link">2</button>
    <button class="nav-link">3</button>
  </nav>

</header>

<body>
  <div id="background">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA8zp.png I want the text saying "Nebula Coin" inside the header and when I zoom in and zoom out for it to scale like the rest. Margins do not work for some reason. I can add margins to the image icon and the buttons to make them move but not the text.

Comment: Your header must go inside the body tag

Comment: thank you so much I started 2 days ago so these rookie mistakes keep happening hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

this because of the font-size now when you add padding on it te title will still in his place because it fit his container.

```css
html {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #32CD32;
}

#background {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, #e800e8, #a800a8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #880088;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}

#title {
  margin-right: 3vw;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
padding:1em;
}

#header-img {
  margin-right: 53vw;
  transform: scale(2.3);
  margin-bottom: 0.8vh;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-link {
  width: 15%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
<header id="header">
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <h1 id="title">Nebula Coin</h1>
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/202463/isolated/lists/1b4829ac9ea7a1093b4abb1fb0b2f4cf-american-dollar-bill-flat-icon.png" alt="" id="header-img" />
    <button class="nav-link">1</button>
    <button class="nav-link">2</button>
    <button class="nav-link">3</button>
  </nav>

</header>

  <div id="background">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```